# Scale of the correlation coefficient: is "r = .40 is twice as strong as r = .20" allowed/correct?

Tags: correlation, mean, interpretation, scales

Some people recommend the following procedure to calculate the mean of several correlation coefficients: transform the coefficients by Fisher's $z$ transformation, calculate the mean of that, and transform the result back.

This made me think what about the scale of the correlation coefficient. Generally, I have the feeling that the coefficient is treated as a ratio scaled variable: $r = .40$ is a relationship that is twice as strong as $r = .20$. But is this correct?

Comment: That depends on what is "to be strong" for you currently. The meaning of the magnitude. Sometimes we'll average r, sometimes r^2, sometimes Fisher's z, and sometimes other representation/transform of r.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen this wording so in practice it seems odd. On the principle, "strength of relationship" is not measured as an amount. In addition to the good points made by @ttphns, I will mention that e.g. $-0.5$ is as strong as $0.5$, so $|r|$ is yet another scale.

Comment: "Strong" is ill-defined and therefore ought to be avoided.  But if you were to remove it, so your statement reads "$r=0.40$ is twice $r=0.20$," it would be accurate.  That still begs the questions raised by @ttnphns and Nick Cox concerning how you ought to be comparing the correlation coefficients.  Taking a ratio of correlation coefficients is practically meaningless and almost impossible to interpret, suggesting "twice" might be a misleading way to make the comparison.

Answer (score -2):

You need to calculate the r^2. R^2 = .16 is four times as strong as r^2 = .04

Comment: Why is this the correct answer to OP's question? How does it address the concern that OP raises?

Comment: Of greater importance in many cases is $\sqrt{1-R^2}$ because that estimates the typical size of a residual. On that basis, $R^2=0.16$ is only $1.07$ times "as strong" as $R^2 = 0.04.$